# Does the product of these Mersenne-related superparticulars converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

If $M_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Mersenne prime, does this series converge?
$$\prod_{n=1}^∞ \frac{M_n+1}{M_n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course yes. Your product is less than:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n-1}\right)$$
that is convergent since
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1} $$
is convergent.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any convergence tests. Thank you.